# Argument being passed as integer?

Tags: c++, vector

```
class Game {
  public:
    void draw_string(const char *text, int x, int y, TTF_Font *font, SDL_Color color, bool center);

  private:
    void spawn_enemies(vector <Enemy*>& enemies);
};
```

I have that as the definition of a class, and the definition of spawn_enemies is as follows:

```
void Game::spawn_enemies(vector <Enemy*>& enemies) {
  if (rand() % difficulty == 0) {
    Enemy *enemy = new Enemy(screen, zombie_image);
    enemies.push_back(enemy);
  }
}
```

And then I call spawn_enemies:

```
game.spawn_enemies(enemies);
```

And I define enemies as:

```
vector<Enemy*> enemies;
```

Any idea of why I get this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘Game::spawn_enemies(std::vector<Enemy*>&)’            
note: candidate is:
note: void Game::spawn_enemies(int)
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::vector<Enemy*>’ to ‘int’
```

Comment: You declare spawn_enemies() as private - not sure how you can call it on an instance of Game as if it were a public method? Try making it public. Not sure why that weird error though...

Comment: I also tried to declare it as public, but it still didn't work. In fact, I get the same error.

Comment: Paste *full error*. And triple check the code you're pasting, include all relevant bits.

Comment: Temporarily change the declared parameter to spawn_enemies() to double and comment out the contents of that method - leave the call to the method using the vector. Does the warning now change to say double instead of int? It's almost as if it doesn't understand the vector in the header file and assumes a default of int.

Comment: This is most likely a header file/declaration ordering issue.  You need to define `enemies` before you use it.  If you have other definitions of classes that have a `spawn_enemies` you might be accidentally getting one of those, etc.

Comment: Does the error message include a line number? If so, examine that line. If that doesn't help, make the shortest possible program that produces that error message and paste that program into the question. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @JTeagle, now it says "no known conversion from for argument 1 from (vector) to 'double'.

From the place where I write the function spawn_enemies, the code can't access the other enemies variable, so it is definitely looking for the vector, which is the argument of the function.

Comment: Guys, I just got it, I wasn't doing "using namespace std;" on the header file, so it wasn't including vector, which was causing a lot of weird mistakes, thank you all, though!

Comment: Don't do `using namespace std;`, especially in a header. Spell the qualified name (`std::vector`), it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wasn't doing "using namespace std;" on the header file, so it wasn't
>   including vector, which was causing a lot of weird mistakes

This is why it is good to use std:: instead of using namespace std.
It makes your code easier to understand and your code will still compile if they ever add Game or Enemy to the STL (Unlikely, I know).  And it would allow you to add your own version of vector, min/max etc. if you really wanted to (I wouldn't recommend it though).

Comment: The only trouble with qualifying vector all over the place - even though your comments are very valid - is that it bloats the code unnecessarily. I prefer 'using std::vector' as a compromise.